# Dynamically resizing a DIV and iframe (a site inside) at a same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue and trying to figure it out..

I’m using a jqueryUI library to use .resizable() and I use google in the iframe just for an example. I'm using the latest version of jquery. Here is the front end example.

```
<div class=”Panel”>
              <div class=”ResizeDiv”>
                  <div class=”PanelBody”>
                      <div class=”PlaceHolderView”>
                         <iframe src=”www.google.com” > </iframe>
                       </div>
                   </div>
              </div>   
</div>
```

The code above is dynamically added using for loop jsp. So I'm trying not to make all other div elements resize at a same time. Each of them needs to be unique. Here is the javascript side.

```
$(“.ResizeDiv”).resizable({
     resize: function(event, ui) {
..due its code when resizing .ResizeDiv. This is when adding “-webkit-transform:scale(NUMBER)” style inside the iframe (example $(this).children()...css({"-webkit-transform": scale(number)}). So when resizing ResizeDiv, it dynamically get the scale and resize the iframe along with ResizeDiv. 
      }
})
```

My goal- when resizing the ResizeDiv div dynamically, the iframe should also resize inside of it. The google browser should also resize to fit the iframe

The issue- when I resize the ResizeDiv div, the iframe is not resizing equally along with the ResizeDiv. I want the iframe (along with the browser inside of it) to fit exactly with the ResizeDiv. I’m using “-webkit-transform:scale(NUMBER)” in order to resize the browser itself in the iframe but I couldn’t figure out the correct calculation of getting the scale number so it fits perfectly with ResizeDiv.

I hope this makes sense. I've been trying to figure this out in the past days. Please can anyone insist me? I highly appreciated!

--Here is also an example. Noticed that the iframe is inside the blue border div. If i click and drag the bottom right corner of the DIV, the iframe and the site inside the iframe should enlarge at a same time.Though i can make the iframe move along with the div but not the site inside the iframe which is why i used “-webkit-transform:scale(NUMBER)”. But the issue I'm having is when i enlarge the blue border div, the site inside the iframe does not shrinks or enlarge with the blue div. It will enlarge or shrinks quickly. 
[image]

Comment: I would suggest using CSS on the iFrame, such that `width: 100%; height: 100%` will cause the iFrame to always be 100% of the parent `div`. Not sure what you mean by the source resizing.

Comment: I made an update. i hope this makes sense